# get details from ipconfig python

Tags: python, ipconfig

I am looking for a short command to get an network interface ip address by its name, in python.
it did not work with socket.getaddr()
for example, this is my details:
[image]

I want a func so:

> `x=func('vEthernet (VIC Ethernet)')`

so that x will be 10.10.255.254
i dont want to run ipconfig and parse it

thanks

Comment: currently this amounts to a 'write my code for me' question.  Such questions are off topic here.  In any case the title doesn't line up with the q: do you, or do you not, want to use `ipconfig`?

Comment: I dont want to use ipconfig

Answer (score 0):

you can use this function to get the primary IP:

```
import socket
def get_ip():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.settimeout(0)
    try:
        # doesn't even have to be reachable
        s.connect(('10.255.255.255', 1))
        IP = s.getsockname()[0]
    except Exception:
        IP = '127.0.0.1'
    finally:
        s.close()
    return IP
```

to get all ips you can use [netifaces](https://pypi.org/project/netifaces/) :

```
from netifaces import interfaces, ifaddresses, AF_INET
for ifaceName in interfaces():
    addresses = [i['addr'] for i in ifaddresses(ifaceName).setdefault(AF_INET, [{'addr':'No IP addr'}] )]
    print(' '.join(addresses))
```

output:

```
No IP addr
No IP addr
No IP addr
No IP addr
192.168.0.104
127.0.0.1
```

Comment: hi, it works only for the hostname you written. I want to choose the interface name and send it to the func

Answer (score 0):

It returns the IP address and port as a tuple.

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.connect(("8.8.8.8", 80))
print(s.getsockname()[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

scapy module has a func the does it - `get_if_addr(iface_name)`
thanks for everyone